# JWebUnit to test File Upload

Tags: java, unit-testing, file-upload

I am trying to test a File Upload field with [JWebUnit](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/overview-summary.html) but I do not know how to do that. I see that [JWebUnit has a dependancy on common-fileupload](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/jwebunit-commons-tests/dependencies.html) so I expect that this is possible but I can see nothing documenting it so the feature may as well not exist. I have done some extensive searching and looking so I think soon I might even go as far as check out the JWebUnit code for traces but I'm still not sure how to get this done. How do I make sure that a file is added to the HTTP Post when the form submit button is clicked in the test? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so as it turns out, after some searching through the [source code I found a test on line 77 of a test file](https://github.com/JWebUnit/jwebunit/blob/79a333316015f46b0cca0fe1a87e6c13e1378a52/jwebunit-commons-tests/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/jwebunit/tests/FormSubmissionTest.java#L81) that basically explains how it works by doing it.